# onBackPressed() in an RecyclerView Adapter, onClickListener back to fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, listadapter

I'm creating an adapter for a RecyclerView; currently creating an onClickListener to the items within the RecyclerView; I wish to go to a fragment which I can't seem to do, so I have tried to add onBackPressed() with super.onBackPressed in the method as the fragment is on the previous page; I have called this in the onClickListener and it doesn't seem to work, any ideas how I can fix this?

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
  TextView text1, text2, text3;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
      super(itemView);
      itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        // This onClick doesn't accept onBackPressed() or popBackStack(), however I need to get this to the previous page which is a fragment.
        }
      });
```

Comment: post some code so others can see and help you.

Comment: public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView text1, text2, text3;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // This onClick doesn't accept onBackPressed() or popBackStack(), however I need to get this to the previous page which is a fragment.
                }
            });

Comment: Edit the question to add the code instead of pasting in a comment :-)

Comment: You have to pass the Context to the adapter. you can then get fragment manager from the Context.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I just need the onBackPressed() working however when implementing the method with super.onBackPressed() it shows as if it's not identified

Answer (score 0):

Use getFragmentManager().popBackStack() method

Comment: this method doesn't seem to work; this onClick is implemented in the Adapter of the RecyclerView